# Rewrite custom post type url with another custom post type

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have two custom post types `Location` and `House`.

I am trying to rewrite the the url of house post type to `/location/%LocationName%/house`

I've used `add_filter('post_type_link', 'postTypeLink', 13, 3)` to replace `%LocationName%` and the permalink did change to the format I want, however when I click on the link, it only throws out a page not found error.

I have printed the `wp_query` and found out wp is still trying to do a `Location` query but with a name `%LocationName%/house`

e.g. House has a post `yellow`. So, the url domain.com/location/london/house/yellow will make a location query with name `/london/house/yellow` instead of a house query with name `yellow`. it caused page not found as location doesn't have any such post.

I've tried to use `add_rewrite_rule` or save the permalink but it only led to the same result.

The code is below.

```
    add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_tag', 10, 0 );

    function rewrite_tag() {
       add_rewrite_tag( '%locationName%', '([^/]*)/?$', 'locationName=' );
       add_rewrite_rule(
           '^location/([^/]*)/?$/house',
           'index.php?post_type=house&locationName=$matches[1]',
           'top');
       flush_rewrite_rules(false);
    }

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'Manage Research Publication',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu'  => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'location/%locationName%/house',
                'with_front'=> false,  
                'hierarchical' => true
        ),
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-clipboard',
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'rest_base'             => 'house',
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',

    );
    register_post_type( 'house', $args );

    add_filter('post_type_link', 'postTypeLink', 13, 3);
    function postTypeLink($link, $post)    {
      global $post;
       if (get_post_type($post) === 'location') {

           $location = a variable from global post
           $link = str_replace('%LocationLName%', $location, $link);


       }
       return $link;
    }
```